# Julia: add custom message in assert?

Tags: julia, assert, assertions, assertion

In Python I can add a custom message to an assertion to help with code development:

```py
assert False, "Expected true"
```

How can I do the same in Julia?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/stdlib/base/#Base.@assert):

```
@assert false "Expected true"
```

> `@assert cond [text]`
>
> Throw an `AssertionError` if `cond` is `false`. Preferred syntax for writing assertions. Message `text` is optionally displayed upon assertion failure.

Comment: @assert exists(link) "documentation link 404's"

Comment: Here are the docs: https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/base/#Base.@assert